# How to change the color styles in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors, eclipse-juno

I am using eclipse JUNO.

When the cursor goes over the variable name (in resource and debug perspective) the details of the variable name in displayed in a small window like a box..How to change the color of the window and its details..

In my case  the color is actually in black background and white foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse on Ubuntu? There this seems to be a common problem caused by default color settings of the operating system.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1620/how-to-fix-unreadable-tooltips-in-eclipse-helios
https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Juno and the problem is still there.  I believe it is a bug in Eclipse: unchecking "System Default" in Java > Editor > Source Hover background has no effect.  Eclipse continues to use the system-provided colors even when changing the settings.

This seems to be a long-standing problem with Eclipse developers blaming Ubuntu.